# android, httpurlconnection error

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm running the following test Java script from the [Android HttpURLConnection docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
```

Eclipse (on my Mac) is telling me there's a system error when I run this in the Android Emulator:

`01-13 13:44:32.767: WARN/System.err(1382): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`

(Incidentally when I do the equivalent in Objective-C/Cocoa there's no problem at all.)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your application is not allowed to access the network unless it has declared that its going to in the AndroidManifest.xml file, add this inside the `<manifest>` element.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I added that permission statement, rebooted eclipse and uninstalled the app on the device many times, still no joy.  Any other ideas?