# Communication with server without INTERNET permission

Tags: android, network-programming, httpurlconnection, privacy, android-permissions

I am planning to develop an Android app that communicates with a server that I operate. Answers to [android, httpurlconnection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676897/android-httpurlconnection-error) state that classes such as `HttpURLConnection` and `HttpsURLConnection` require granting the "full network access" permission (`android.permission.INTERNET`) to the app. Someone on a forum told me that  for the vast majority of apps, `android.permission.INTERNET` is unacceptably intrusive on the user's privacy, and that there exist other ways for an app to communicate with a server operated by its developer that do not require such an intrusive permission. From [this post](http://slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=7200329&cid=49399211):

> And the same app will ask for full network access, even though if you look at the traffic, almost all of them are using HTTP to talk to their services, and they have no legit need for full network access. However, it lets them look at what all your network connections are.
>
> [...]
>
> Also, no, you don't need "full network access" to access anything outside a web browser. You only need it to go off port 80 HTTP. You can still just use a subdomain for the remote app API. You're conflating two different permissions.

When I asked for further clarification on how to get this going in Android, so that I could go look it up on developer.android.com, the reply was "your ignorance doesn't demonstrate anything."

So how should an app communicate with a server operated by its developer without `android.permission.INTERNET`? Or is there a reliable source stating that this is impossible in Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> that there exist other ways for an app to communicate with a server operated by its developer that do not require such an intrusive permission

Not really.

As far as I can tell from the rant that you linked to, the ranter is complaining that there is no IP- or host-level whitelisting possible in Android's permission system. `INTERNET` grants access to the whole Internet. This is a valid complaint about the OS, but there is nothing that an app developer can really do about it. *Users* can, to the extent that they are willing to install firewall-type apps (either pseudo-VPNs or true firewalls, the latter requiring root). *ROM modders* can. Google could. Device manufacturers could. App developers cannot.

I mean, in theory, the app could speak to the server using Bluetooth (with limited range) or NFC (with *really* limited range), but those are generally deemed impractical.

With regards to the ranter's claim that "you don't need "full network access" to access anything outside a web browser. You only need it to go off port 80 HTTP", that is fairly ridiculous. For example, resolving a domain name requires you "go off port 80 HTTP", and that definitely fails sans `INTERNET` permission.

I don't have a sample app that I can try that would work with a plain IP address, so I cannot absolutely validate right now that accessing a plain IP address on port 80 could work without `INTERNET`. If that proves true, that's a security flaw in Android that would need to be fixed, and I'll be *very* surprised if this is the case.

> Or is there a reliable source stating that this is impossible in Android?

I'll state that there is no practical way for an Android app to talk to a server, outside of perhaps `localhost`, that does not involve the `INTERNET` permission.

Whether a source is reliable is a statement of opinion. I'll put [my track record](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) up against any random Slashdot poster, though.

Comment: `outside of perhaps localhost` meaning when using local host its ok with out internet? but for local server can my app still work to communicate with local server? with out internet if there is a way what is that way. right now i am using `AsyncHttpClient` which does not work with out internet.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the apps on your Android device. The overwhelming majority of them will use the INTERNET permission. What makes them useful is their ability to talk to various web services of varying types.

Users are accustomed to agreeing to this permission when installing apps and won't be put off your app if it asks for it.